# Structs inside classes for global constants in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, global-scope

I'm using an `Util` class in swift as helper class. Besides functions I want to implement some constants with custom colors.

It's correct to use a Struct in this way?

```
class Util: NSObject {

struct Colors {
    static let white = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    static let orangeCantaloupe = UIColor(red: 1, green: 204/255, blue: 102/255, alpha: 1)
    static let greyMercury = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 230/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1)
    static let greyMagnesium = UIColor(red: 179/255, green: 179/255, blue: 179/255, alpha: 1)

}

class func anyFunction() {

.......
 }
}
```

Comment: You should make a helper function to produce `UIColor`s which abstracts away all those `/255`s

Comment: The static variable in ```Util``` class move to ```UIColor``` using ```extension```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `UIColor` with new colours:

```
extension UIColor {
   static let white = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
   static let orangeCantaloupe = UIColor(red: 1, green: 204/255, blue: 102/255, alpha: 1)
   static let greyMercury = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 230/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1)
   static let greyMagnesium = UIColor(red: 179/255, green: 179/255, blue: 179/255, alpha: 1)
}
```

In contexts where a `UIColor` is expected, the type can be implied, so you can write just `something.color = .orangeCantaloupe`

Alternatively, you can keep them in a seperate name space (for clarity over convenience), like `BrandColors`. An empty enum works best, so you know that nobody will accidentally instantiate a senseless object.